# How to filter all special char (beside underscores ) for display allow and not allow?

Tags: javascript, php

How to filter all special char (beside underscores ) for display allow and not allow ?

on my wish , i will allow only text , number and underscores

but when i test this code , i try fill `123456abcd&` in input it's will show

`123456abcd& available`  how can i do for filter all special char (beside underscores )

index.php

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript">
       var HttPRequest = false;

       function doCallAjax() {
          HttPRequest = false;
          if (window.XMLHttpRequest) { // Mozilla, Safari,...
             HttPRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
             if (HttPRequest.overrideMimeType) {
                HttPRequest.overrideMimeType('text/html');
             }
          } else if (window.ActiveXObject) { // IE
             try {
                HttPRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
             } catch (e) {
                try {
                   HttPRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (e) {}
             }
          } 

          if (!HttPRequest) {
             alert('Cannot create XMLHTTP instance');
             return false;
          }

          var url = 'check_char.php';
          var pmeters = "CUsername=" + encodeURI( document.getElementById("CheckUsername").value);
            HttPRequest.open('POST',url,true);
            HttPRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            HttPRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-length", pmeters.length);
            HttPRequest.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");
            HttPRequest.send(pmeters);
            HttPRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
            {

                if(HttPRequest.readyState == 3)  // Loading Request
                {
                    document.getElementById("mySpan").innerHTML = "..";
                }
                if(HttPRequest.readyState == 4) // Return Request
                {
                    if(HttPRequest.responseText == 'Y')
                    {
                        window.location = 'AjaxPHPRegister3.php';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        document.getElementById("mySpan").innerHTML = HttPRequest.responseText;
                    }
                }       
            }
       }
    </script>


        <input size="30" tabindex="1" type="text" name="CheckUsername" id="CheckUsername" onchange="JavaScript:doCallAjax();" 
         value="<?php if(isset($_POST['CheckUsername'])) echo $_POST['CheckUsername']; ?>"> 
        <span id="mySpan"></span>
```

check_char.php

```
<?php
$strUsername = $_POST[CUsername];
            $special_char_total = strlen(preg_replace('@[a-z0-9_\-\.]@', '', $strUsername));
            $text_and_number_char_total = strlen(preg_replace('@[^a-z0-9]@', '', $strUsername));

            if ($special_char_total > 0)
                { echo "Username can only contain letters, numbers and underscores (and no spaces!)"; }
            elseif ($text_and_number_char_total < 1)
                { echo "Username must have at lest 1 letter or number"; }
            else
                {
                    echo"$_POST[CUsername] available.";
                }
?>
```

Comment: [Why is `$foo[bar]` wrong?](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.foo-bar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is to check for the allowed characters and count those. See if the below works for you:

```
<?php
$strUsername = $_POST[CUsername]; 
$strlen =  strlen($strUsername);          
$valid_char_count = strlen(preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9_]/', '', $strUsername));

if (($valid_char_count < $strlen) || $valid_char_count < 1) {
 if($valid_char_count < $strlen) {
    echo "Username can only contain letters, numbers and underscores (and no spaces!)";
 }

 if ($valid_char_count < 1) { 
    echo "Username must have at lest 1 letter or number"; 
    }
} else {
    echo $strUsername." available";
}
?>
```

Comment: @uzasnik ... this can be comment

Comment: i thing cause problem is `index.php`

ok, i thing ajax cannot send special char like `&` to `check_char.php` page

Comment: ok , i tested when i fill `abcd1234&&&` in input it's show `available` i want to show `Username can only contain letters, numbers and underscores (and no spaces!)` because `abcd1234&&&` have `&&&` is special char

Comment: That is weird. I have tested the PHP script above and it works for me with abcd1234&&& input => it returns "Username can only contain letters, numbers and underscores (and no spaces!)"

Comment: are you apply file `index.php`